# Is there a way to save all files, commit and upload in one command in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I find myself doing a lot of hotfixes on my code, and I have to test on a remote machine. In visual studio code, is there a way to set up a macro that will

1. save all open files
2. commit changes (with blank or random commit message)
3. upload all commits

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to run multiple commands at once, so you will need an extension. With [ryuta46.multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), and this configuration, `Ctrl+Alt+S` will save and push all of your files

settings.json (`Ctrl+,`):

```
{
    "multiCommand.commands": [{
        "command":"multiCommand.syncAllFiles",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
                "args": "syncAll"
            },
            "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal"
        ]
    }]
}
```

I've added a command to toggle the terminal after the command is run so that it doesnt stay open every time you run the command. Unfortunately, it happens even if the terminal was already open, so if you don't want it to do that, just remove that line

keybindings.json (`Ctrl+K` `Ctrl+S`):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.syncAllFiles" },
},
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "syncAll",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "git add .;git commit -m 'Automatic Commit';git pull;git push",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was perfect. Only modifications I made was: instead of doing `git pull; git push`, I just did `git pull origin master` which was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could set up a task to do the work for you https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

If this is not enough, let me know and I can write you an example.
Best thing in tasks is, you can bind them to a hotkey

Answer (score 1):

Without saving files:

`keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "git add . && git commit -a -m 'Update' && git push\u000D"
    }
}
```

About `sendSequence`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding

---

With saving files:

`MoreThanTom`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864886/451710) adjusted:

(Using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

`settings.json`:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.syncAllFiles",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.files.saveAll",
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": {
                    "text": "git add . && git commit -a -m 'Update' && git push\u000D"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+s",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.syncAllFiles" },
}
```

No need for `tasks`.